# Set a date based on other dates?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, date, charts

I need to set a chart to start at midnight of the current day and end just before midnight of the next day...
I'm trying to do something like this:
`minChartDate = currentDate.fullYear,currentDate.month,currentDate.date,0,0,0,0;`

where `currentDate:Date;` is the day currently selected.

I'm getting an implicit coercion error between the Number to Date type, as if currentDate.fullYear is a Date, but according to the documentation it should be a number. Or is my syntax defining this incorrect?  Also wondering if there's a simpler way to get the min and max dates than this!
(the reason I am setting this is so that it starts at midnight rather than at the first data point in the series).

I'm also getting a weird error 'maximum' values of type Date cannot be represented in text.. it said I need a Date type object for the minimum and maximum so I'm really not sure what it's talking about...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code will make a date object set to 0:00 on today.

```
var minChartdate:Date= new Date();
minChartdate.hours=0;
minChartdate.minutes=0;
minChartdate.seconds=0;
minChartdate.milliseconds=0;
trace(minChartdate)
```

To make one for the next day:

```
var minChartdate:Date= new Date();
minChartdate.time = minChartdate.time+1000*60*60*24 // one day in milliseconds
minChartdate.hours=0;
minChartdate.minutes=0;
minChartdate.seconds=0;
minChartdate.milliseconds=0;
trace(minChartdate);
```

This script moves the date object forward by 24 hours, and then sets hours, mins,sec,milisecs to 0.

Note: This is not 100% correct solution, it can fail on days, when the hours are adjusted because of daylight saving time changes.

Comment: You can patch it for the daylight savings time by setting d.hours to 12 before you add 24 hours. That way, after addition, d.hours will be 11, 12 or 13, but always the same (correct) day.